Choices js with wire:model.live bespoke javascript
I'm currently using choices js for a searchable select but now, when i use it with live:model.live, after my result reload, the select changes to back to a normal select and can't be used as live search anymore (error: Cannot access offset of type string on string)
this is my current code
 <div class="col-span-2">
            <select id="group" wire:model.live="group">
                <option value="">Group</option>
                @foreach ($options as $item)
                    <option value="{{ $item['value'] }}">{{ $item['label'] }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>

 @script
        <script>
            const groupChoice = new Choices('#group', {
                removeItemButton: true,
                allowHTML: false
            });
        </script>
    @endscript

while using wire:ignore kinda solve it, its not really a solution for me as i still use the select option elsewhere or should i post in a different question instead?
<div class="col-span-2" wire:ignore>
            <select id="group" wire:model.live="group">
                <option value="">Group</option>
                @foreach ($options as $item)
                    <option value="{{ $item['value'] }}">{{ $item['label'] }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>

and i've tried this and other similar to it:
 const select = document.getElementById('group');

            // Attach a change event listener using Livewire's bespoke JavaScript
            select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
                // Handle the select change event here
                select.destroy();
                groupChoice = new Choices('#group', {
                removeItemButton: true,
                allowHTML: false
            });
                console.log('Selected value:', e.target.value);
               
            });

the Selected value: log came out just fine but the dropdown didn't change back to searchable

Please explain better what you mean by "while using wire:ignore kinda solve it, its not really a solution for me as i still use the select option elsewhere or should i post in a different question instead?"

wire:ignore will make the select stays as a choices js but if i use a select in a modal for an edit form, the data from db wont be assigned to the select

The problem is not the wire:ignore attribute but the fact that choices-js can't detect the initial value.
To allow this, a possible solution is to use the Blade @selected() directive:
The class
class Choice extends Component
{
    public $group = 2;


    public function render()
    {
        $options = [

            ['value' => 1, 'label' => '1st choice'],
            ['value' => 2, 'label' => '2nd choice'],
            ['value' => 3, 'label' => '3rd choice'],
            ['value' => 4, 'label' => '4th choice'],
            ['value' => 5, 'label' => '5th choice'],

        ];

        return view('livewire.choice', ['options' => $options]);
    }


    public function updatedGroup()
    {
        $this->group = (int)$this->group['value']; // decide for yourself whether you need the 'cast'
    }
}

The view
<div class="col-span-2">

    <div>
        @dump ($group)
    </div>

    <div wire:ignore>

        <select id="group" wire:model.live="group">

            <option value="">Group</option>

            @foreach ($options as $item)

                <option value="{{ $item['value'] }}" @selected($group == $item['value'])> {{ $item['label'] }} </option>

            @endforeach

        </select>

    </div>

</div>

@script
<script>

    const groupChoice = new Choices('#group', {

        removeItemButton: true,
        allowHTML: false
    });

</script>
@endscript

Since choices-js updates the wire:model with an associative array, we can transform it as a single value using the updatedGroup() method

it's still using wire:ignore. i guess i'll just stick to that and find another workaround for my other select

So I still haven't been able to understand why you don't want to use wire:ignore can you explain better?

sorry for the misunderstanding. its not that i don't want to use wire:ignore. i'm trying to find if there's a general way to solve my issue

i'll try to elaborate. so basically, i have a parent livewire component view that has a select #group which uses wire:model.live for searching function. using wire:ignore for #group works for both searching and the select staying as choicesjs. then i have child livewire component which also uses select. this is the one that i couldnt get to work (i found a workaway tho https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78781101/choicesjs-with-shared-blade-view).

Can you edit the question by adding the not-working child component?
