choicesjs with shared blade view
i have a post livewire component in which has 2 child: createpost and updatepost. both createpost and updatepost has the same blade view and hence they render the same view:
return view('components.test.modal-form');
createpost is called from a button post blade view and updatepost is called from the button insinde list in post blade view
inside modal-form, i'm using choicesjs for a searchable select. however the select are just plain one instead of choices js selects
if i use wire:ignore, the select is choices js but it wont get the data when i use it to update.
both form codes are exactly the same except for the button and title so i trying to avoid redundant codes

this is what i found as a workaround. hopefully there's an answer that follows the standard practice or a cleaner solution
i decided that each livewire component have their own livewire view so their render became:
return view('livewire.test.update');
//return view('livewire.test.create');

and inside them i place the blade component
{{-- livewire.test.update.blade.php --}}
 {{-- the $selectId is because the select can't have the same id for choicesjs to work --}}
<div>
    <x-test.modal-form :$formType :$options :$selectId></x-test.modal-form>

    @script
        <script>
            const f_groupChoice = new Choices('#{{ $selectId }}', {
                removeItemButton: true,
                allowHTML: false
            });
 
            // this function not in the create livewire since only used during update
            $wire.on('choicesjs', () => {
                // f_groupChoice.setChoiceByValue('test');
                
            })
        </script>
    @endscript
</div>

